# how to route to a different page in react?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router, amazon-cognito

I want to redirect to two different pages on login by the user. Can anyone explain how I can do so in the following code? I am using aws cognito for authentication. if the group of the user is employee it should redirect to a different page.

I am currently unable to access the cognito group outside Auth.currentSession() function.

```
const Login= () => {
  Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
    let cognitoGroups = res.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]
    console.log(`group: ${cognitoGroups}`)
  if(cognitoGroups[0]==="Employee")
  console.log('employee!');
  });
      return(
        <div>
          {cognitoGroups=="Employee"} ? 
          <Route path='/employee' component={Emlogin} />
          <Redirect from="login" to="employee" /> 
          :
          <Route path='/manager' component={Mglogin} />
          <Redirect from="login" to="manager" />
          <AmplifySignOut />
        </div>
      )
  }
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `{... ? ... : ...}` incorrectly, in the jsx part your condition needs to be something like this

```
let cognitoGroups = "Employee"
      return(
        <div>
          {cognitoGroups ? 
          (<Route path='/employee' component={Emlogin} />
          <Redirect from="login" to="employee" />)
          :
          (<Route path='/manager' component={Mglogin} />
          <Redirect from="login" to="manager" />
          <AmplifySignOut />)}
        </div>)
```

Also, if you want to check for the type of user, you can add a condition like `{cognitoGroups == "employees" ? doThis() : elseDoThat()}`

Comment: okay I will change that. my issue now is that I have removed the let cognitoGroups = "Employee" statement as I want it to read the value of cognito group from the current session, but now when I try to access the cognito group, the error says that it is undefined. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: you need to define the variable at the top level in order for your return() to be able to read it, you can define a null variable at the very start and then modify the value as you wish.

Comment: ok I will try and see if it works. thank you for your help